# Mysql Left Join (1 to many relationship)

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 2 tables 
A user is assigned to 1 group a group can have more than 1 user

table a 6 users (ID, Name, GroupID)
Except for 1, all users are assigned to a group
Table b 4 groups(ID, GroupName)

I would like to list all groups and the users in each group even if no user is assigned

```
SELECT groups.Group_ID, groups.Group_name,
       Group_concat(users.User_ID order by User_ID) AS assigned
FROM groups
LEFT JOIN users 
     ON groups.Group_ID = users.GroupID
GROUP BY groups.Group_ID
```

This only returns the listing of groups.

Comment: you can add  SELECT users.*, ... in you query

Comment: Why LEFT JOIN and not FULL OUTTER JOIN?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI If you have to ask, well, MySQL might not be the right thread for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your problem is that you are storing lists if group ids in a single column.  You should fix your data structure and have a `UserGroups` table, with one row per user and one per group.

Sometimes, we a stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.  In that case, you can use `find_in_set()`:

```
On find_in_set(g.groupid, u.groupids) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting nothing but NULL values in your `assigned` column in your result set, it's evidence that your `ON groups.Group_ID = users.GroupID` condition is never being satisfied.

You probably should check your tables' contents to see whether the ID columns you use in that `ON` condition work the way you think they do.

Also, notice that you're using a [nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). This can sometimes cause confusion. Try `GROUP BY groups.Group_ID, groups.Group_name` and see if your results improve.